# Under constant ddos, even after switching 3 differnet routers?

Tags: ddos

I started getting ddosed when i pissed some minecraft nerd offt on some twitch chat, which he got banned from, and i never saw him again, but i moved to a hotel for about a week, and i kept getting ddosed. I moved to another hotel, and nothing happened, anothere hotel, nothing happened, then i moved in to my new house, got brand new internet literaly today, and im being syn flooded 30 minutes after the router is set up. My router logs are below.[image: router logs]

i cant access games like clash of clans and fifa 15, but i can browse the internet perfectly fine, watch youtube ect.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the fact you claim to be getting knocked offline even though you have moved several times, I would guess that you linked your Skype account or some other service that exposes your IP address on your twitch account, which the attacker is using to find your IP.

Answer (score 0):

There is not much you can do here, Do NOT delete your logs. if this keeps going on get your ISP involved . Close all unused ports, use [Shields up](https://www.grc.com/shieldsup) to check and see what other people can see from your connection. turn off: "respond to WAN ping" ad enable DDOS prevention/mitigation if available.